# Failed to build UWP project with Visual Studio 2017 due to missing reference

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to build a UWP project using Visual Studio 2017.
Without success :(

Here is the error messages content:

*error CS0012: The type 'IAsyncOperationWithProgress<,>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.
error CS0012: The type 'IAsyncActionWithProgress<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.
error CS0012: The type 'IAsyncOperation<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.
error CS0012: The type 'IAsyncAction' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.
error CS0103: The name 'Package' does not exist in the current context*

The code lines inducing the errors all contain the await keyword and are like that:

```
var storageFolder = Task.Run(async () => await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(folderPath));
```

The "Quick actions" propose me to *Add reference to 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.*

When I try, I have, in the Reference Manager' dialog :

*The Universal SDK is already referenced. Please us the Object Browser to explore the references in th Universal Windows SDK.*

And

*No Framework assemblies were found on the machine*

I un-installed VS and re-install => nothing changed

I un-installed all features/applications referencing .net and visual Studio and re-install VS => nothing changed

I tried installing the Windows 10 SDK (10.0.14393) before or after installing VS => nothing changed

I really have no idea of what goes wrong with my dev environment.
Do you know what the error messages mean ?
And does someone can help me to fix it?

TIA

Comment: Try `var storageFolder = await storageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(folderPath);` and configure async on the Method this line is in.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know how I fixed the problem.
I "played" with the emulator extensions, especially the Android one.
Without understanding, while uninstalling it, my problem disappears.
Sorry, for the ones who will encounter the same problem I did, I close the discussion as my problem has been fixed, even if I can't explain why.